# Building email from custom web form content

Tags: velo

I am trying to write WIX pagecode to send an email with information included from a WIX custom form

I am using SendGrid to forward the email

I can capture the "form fill" elements easily enough in the email
I also want to capture attachments and I am having difficulty making that work

If I were to share more details here are there people knowledgeable in WIX pageCode who could help ?

I have this form:

https://www.stayontrackvetphysiotherapy.co.uk/new-referral-form

I have this pageCode to capture the content:

```
// Velo API Reference: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/api-overview/introduction

import {sendEmail, sendEmailWithRecipient} from 'backend/email';
import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
  $w("#dataset1").onAfterSave(sendFormData);
});

function sendFormData() {
  const subject = `New Vet Referral Form from ${$w("#input1").value}`;
  const addressObj1 = $w('#addressInput2').value;
  const formattedAddress1 = `${addressObj1.streetAddress.formattedAddressLine}, ${addressObj1.city}, ${addressObj1.subdivision} ${addressObj1.postalCode}, ${addressObj1.country}`;
  const addressObj2 = $w('#addressInput3').value;
  const formattedAddress2 = `${addressObj2.streetAddress.formattedAddressLine}, ${addressObj2.city}, ${addressObj2.subdivision} ${addressObj2.postalCode}, ${addressObj2.country}`;
  const animalDOB = new Date($w("#datePicker1").value);
  const formattedAnimalDOB = animalDOB.toLocaleDateString();
  const recipient = $w("#input8").value;

  // Get the file input elements
  const fileInputs1 = $w("#fileUpload1").value;
  const fileInputs2 = $w("#fileUpload2").value;

  // Create an array of Promises that will resolve with the uploaded files' URLs
  const promises = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < fileInputs1.length; i++) {
    promises.push(fileInputs1[i].getUrl());
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < fileInputs2.length; i++) {
    promises.push(fileInputs2[i].getUrl());
  }

  // Resolve all the Promises and push the URLs to the attachments array
  Promise.all(promises)
    .then(attachments => {
      const body = `New Vet Referral from ${$w("#input1").value}
        \rOwners Name: ${$w("#input1").value}
        \rOwners Email: ${$w("#input2").value}
        \rOwners Contact Number: ${$w("#input3").value}
        \rOwners Address and Post Code: ${formattedAddress2}
        \rAnimals Name: ${$w("#input4").value}
        \rAnimal Species: ${$w("#dropdown1").value}
        \rAnimal Breed: ${$w("#input5").value}
        \rAnimal DOB: ${formattedAnimalDOB}
        \rReferring Vet: ${$w("#input6").value}
        \rReferring Vet Practice: ${$w("#input7").value}
        \rPractice Address and Postcode: ${formattedAddress1}
        \rVet Email: ${$w("#input8").value}
        \rVet Phone: ${$w("#input9").value}
        \rBrief Description of the Problem: ${$w("#input10").value}
        \rPreference for making this appointment: ${$w("#dropdown3").value}`;

      sendEmailWithRecipient(subject, body, recipient, attachments)
        .then(response => console.log(response));

      sendEmail(subject, body, attachments)
        .then(response => console.log(response));
    });
}
```

In my console I see this error:

```
eateConsoleProxy.ts:47 UserError: An error occurred in one of afterSave callbacks
    at eval (index.js:76:37)
    at eval (index.js:17:14)
    at eval (index.js:23:39)
    at eval (index.js:11:19)
    at eval (eventListeners.js:27:58)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at o (eventListeners.js:27:48)
    at fireEvent (eventListeners.js:38:12)
    at eval (index.js:11:19)
    at f (effects.js:128:12)
(anonymous) @ createConsoleProxy.ts:47
eval @ Logger.js:119
eval @ Logger.js:53
log @ Logger.js:87
log @ index.js:28
eval @ index.js:76
eval @ index.js:17
eval @ index.js:23
eval @ index.js:11
eval @ eventListeners.js:27
o @ eventListeners.js:27
fireEvent @ eventListeners.js:38
eval @ index.js:11
f @ effects.js:128
eval @ effects.js:238
await in eval (async)
fold @ result.js:6
eval @ effects.js:231
await in eval (async)
eval @ index.js:81
eval @ index.js:11
eval @ middleware.js:39
try_ @ either.js:59
f @ middleware.js:38
eval @ middleware.js:85
Promise.then (async)
eval @ middleware.js:116
h @ middleware.js:113
m @ middleware.js:129
eval @ middleware.js:159
fold @ either.js:34
eval @ middleware.js:156
v @ datasetApi.js:99
save @ datasetApi.js:193
eval @ index.js:81
eval @ index.js:11
eval @ index.js:127
eval @ index.js:11
eval @ defaultComponentBindingApi.ts:104
eval @ corvidEvents.js:76
(anonymous) @ registerEvent.ts:51
(anonymous) @ clientWorker.ts:141
n @ comlink.ts:312
createConsoleProxy.ts:47 Caused by: TypeError: $w(...).getAttachmentInfo is not a function
    at a (t5vmt.js:34:47)
    at eval (index.js:11:19)
    at eval (index.js:23:39)
    at eval (index.js:11:19)
    at eval (eventListeners.js:27:58)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at o (eventListeners.js:27:48)
    at fireEvent (eventListeners.js:38:12)
    at eval (index.js:11:19)
    at f (effects.js:128:12)
(
```

My code makes no call to any getAttachmentInfo